# How to get the optimal number of clusters using elbow method and return it?

Tags: python, k-means

I need to find a way to return the number of optimal clusters from the elbow method implementation in python. How can I implement the elbow method in order to show the elbow method graph and then return the number of optimal clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `yellowbrick` library for elbow visualisation.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

# Load the IRIS dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
km = KMeans(random_state=42)
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(km, k=(2,10))
 
visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
elbow_value = visualizer.elbow_value
```

Alternatively, you can calculate the derivative between each distortion scores and return the elbow value when the change of the derivative is less than a threshold variable. For more information, check [this](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html#module-yellowbrick.cluster.elbow) documentation.